# Trying to convert PDF to text with fonts

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, pdfbox, txtextcontrol

I am trying to read a PDF file and store the text in a text file.  But while doing this I also want to store font info simultaneously. I am aware of PDFbox for text stropping and fontbox for fonts can they be combined?

Comment: You could be the one to work on a solution where they could be.

Comment: if by 'text file' you mean a `.txt` file, note that a 'plain text' file does not support font information (unless the user wants to read - but not see - the font names that originally were in the PDF).

Comment: BTW - what is 'fontbox' (link please) and what does 'stropping' mean?